# I want to do a rolling average on a set of astronomical measurements

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I am pretty new to data manipulation and I have been tasked with a pretty annoying problem. So far I couldn't find anything similar on the internet to explain how to the various things I need. 
I am trying to take two columns of data, the first is Julian Dates and the second is magnitudes. I want to do something like a rolling average to create data points that are evenly spaced out and puts the point in the middle of the window. Here is an excerpt of the data:

```
6000.87,0.709
6002.884,0.716
6003.72,0.721
6008.86,0.732
6009.748,0.738
6018.887,0.749
```

I need to have a 60 day window (so not the first 60 points but an increase of 60 in the first column), and after each average I need to shift down 20 days and retake the average till I get to the end of my data.
So far I have been able to import the data and run a standard rolling average, however it uses the first sixty points, and I can't figure out how to get it to read the first column. Also it shifts by one data point after it has taken the average, and I need it to move by 20 days. Any help is appreciated. 
Here is what I have made so far:import pandas as pd

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []

readFile = open('trunkdata.txt', 'r')
sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
readFile.close()

for plotPair in sepFile:
    xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
    x.append(float(xAndY[0]))
    y.append(float(xAndY[1]))

arr = pd.DataFrame(y)


data_mean = pd.rolling_mean(arr, 49).shift(-24)

print data_mean


ma.masked_inside(x, 6210, 6249.972)
ma.masked_inside(x, 6935, 6991)
plt.plot(x[len(x) - len(data_mean) :], data_mean, label = 'Smoothed Data')
plt.plot(x,y, label = 'Original Data')

plt.title('Equatorial Data')
plt.xlabel('Julian Date')
plt.ylabel('Q')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this with the `pd.rolling_mean` as the parameters refer to the number of data to use, which in your case vary depending on the value of the date. I can't think of a way to do it avoiding loops but here goes:

```
means = []
arr = pd.Series(y, index=x)
min_date = min(x) 
max_date = min_date + 60
while max_date < max(x):
    means.append(arr.loc[min_date:max_date].mean())
    max_date += 20
    min_date += 20
```

On a side note, I think you're code could be improved in a few ways. Firstly, you could use more descriptive naming like `dates, mags` instead of `x, y`. You could do something like

```
date, mag = plotPair.split(',')
```

However, it looks like that could all be avoided by doing something like

```
pd.read_csv('trunk_data.txt', names=['dates', 'magnitudes'])
```

which should instantly give you a Data Frame with a column for dates and a column for magnitudes.

Comment: Whenever I tried this it seems that max_date was not increasing. So it was always less than max(x) and it would it get stuck in the while loop.

Comment: That was a silly mistake on my part. I was incrementing ```start_date``` instead of ```max_date```. I've edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

So I had to make a few adjustments to get it to work the way I wanted it to. Here are the relevant parts of the file for the question:

```
# runs mean on the Q data from file
Qmean = []
arr = pd.Series(y, index=x)
min_date = min(x)
max_date = min_date + window_size

# actually does the mean
while max_date < 7281:
    Qmean.append(arr.loc[min_date:max_date].mean())
    min_date += window_shift
    max_date += window_shift
```

So the part that says 'window_size' is a variable that controls how many days I am averaging, and 'window_shift' is how may days it will move before taking a new average.

I had some problems getting the averages to plot with the original dates from the data set. It wanted to cram all of the averages into the last two hundred or so days of the data set. So I did this:

```
# gives me dates for the averages
dates = range(start_x, end_x, window_shift)
```

At the time it seemed easier than trying to adjust other parts of the data. All I did was make a group of numbers that increased with the same rate as my average and then plotted the two together to get my graph.

Thanks for the help. Love this site.

Will